# Can't access Outlook on my home wifi

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

My cousin has a Laptop that is running Windows XP and Outlook 2007.  When she's using other internet connections aside from her home wifi everything works fine.  I logged in and checked out her router and there's no ports or any special settings that I could that might cause an issue.  I'm not entirely sure what I should be looking for aside from blocked ports.  Has anyone had this issue?  Could there be a setting in Outlook that could be a fix?

Comment: What do you mean by "Can't access"? Are you getting an error message? Having trouble sending? Receiving? Please update with specific details as to the trouble you're having.

Comment: If it is only happening on the home network, then it may be DNS related.

Comment: We need to know if the problem is with sending, receiving or both. If the problem is sending (most probable) then it will undoubtedly be that her ISP is blocking the SMTP port required to send emails - many ISPs do this to ensure their customers can't be used as open relays (for spamming). If her ISP blocks SMTP for servers it doesn't own then there's nothing she can do with Outlook or her router. She should be able to access a webmail of some sort (such as OWA for an Exchange server).

Comment: Can you access it when your computer is hardwired? (You didn't indicate in your question). I have a suspicion this question has nothing to do with Wi-Fi. If so, the question title needs to be changed to home network. Wi-Fi has absolutely nothing to do with your problem

Answer (score 0):

If your cousin's laptop has outlook configured to use at her work or school, it might have been configured to user that location's outlook exchange server on that local domain or at an IP address that is not externally available. Verify that the outlook send/receive settings are to external addresses. If that is ok, verify the router assumption by trying to connect to outlok at another location (an internet cafe).

Comment: OP quotes **When she's using other internet connections aside from her home wifi everything works fine.** so i would assume its working at other places along with work network

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similiar issue with Outlook and Cisco Anyconnect with my home wifi. I use the same laptop in office and home.

I resolved this issue by unchecking Automatic Configuration from Internet Options -> Connection -> LAN Setting. IE probably keeps the proxy cached in case of Automatic Configuration. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender wont allow Outlook in Private Networks by default. Try Changing the settings of Windows Defender Firewall (WDF) by checking the Private Network tickbox.

Path:
Network and Internet settings > Network and Sharing center >  Windows Defender Firewall (on the bottom left) > Click - "Allow an app or feature through WDF" (on the top left) > Click on "change settings" against Microsoft outlook and tick the unchecked box for Private Network.

Hope this will resolve your issue.